# Got a question about element positioning. CSS Flex

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

I know that absolute positioning of an element in CSS Flex is normally triggered by 'position : absolute' command. However, I would like to ask if an absolute positioned element somehow can have status 'static', 'sticky', 'relative' or 'fixed'. Is it possible anyway?

I know that my question may look not serious enough, but I try nevertheless.

Comment: *can have status* --> define status

Comment: Depends, you can CSS hack but traditionally not; absolute can have a relative element informing the area of positioning.

Comment: If this is a theoretical answer, the answers (if any) are likely to be equally theoretical or based on guesswork as to the assumptions you've made in your code. If you share the code you're working with, so that we can reproduce the problem you're working on, and clearly explain that problem (what's working, what's *not* working, what did you expect?) then we may be able to offer some useful help. Please, read the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines to see what we expect of a question in order to better help you.

Comment: Perhaps it's called value, not status. These definitions are fairly new to me and they leave me puzzled at times.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me, David. However, my questions aren't related to any code because they're taken from a couple of tests. As usual, these examinations are quite annoying, without having much to do with actual coding stuff.

Comment: `position` only allows for one value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: So... am I right that absolute-positioned element can only have 'position : absolute' value, yes?

Comment: If it's in `absolute` position then by definition it cannot be in any of the others.